# Trying to get information from multiple methods

Tags: java

I have to write a program that asks the user for 5 test scores, then using the `calcAverage` and `determineGrade` methods, I need to have the average score and later grade based on that score print to the screen. I'm stuck on what I need to write in the determineGrade method, this is what I have so far...

```
package homework_chap5;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework_Chap5 {

            //Pg 313 #7
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter first test score: ");
       int s1 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter second test score: ");
       int s2 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter third test score: ");
       int s3 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter fourth test score: ");
       int s4 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter fifth test score: ");
       int s5 = s.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Average is " + calcAverage(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5) + 
       "\nYour grade is a " + determineGrade());
       }


    public static float calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5){ 
          float sum = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5;
          float average = sum / 5;
          return average;}  


     public static float determineGrade(int score) {
         return grade;  
     }

}
```

Comment: What you want in Grade Score, what is your criteria ?

Answer (score 0):

Below solution calculates average score from given number of tests. To calculate the grade:

1. Find out the percentage from the average score. For example if the test is conducted for 50 marks then  MAX_SCORE becomes 50 and convert this to percentage.
2. Once you get percentage create a table of percentage to grade mapping. My table looks like this, you can change it based on your grade requirement:

```text
Percentage Grade
90-100     A
80-90      B
60-80      C
<60    D
```

Below is improved code, still it can be made more generic:

```java
    package homework_chap5;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Homework_Chap5 {
        final static int MAX_SCORE = 100; 

            //Pg 313 #7
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter first test score: ");
       int s1 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter second test score: ");
       int s2 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter third test score: ");
       int s3 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter fourth test score: ");
       int s4 = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter fifth test score: ");
       int s5 = s.nextInt();
       float average = calcAverage(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
       System.out.println("Average is " + calcAverage(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5) + 
       "\nYour grade is a " + determineGrade(average,MAX_SCORE));
       }


    public static float calcAverage(int s1, int s2, int s3, int s4, int s5){ 
          float sum = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5;
          float average = sum / 5;
          return average;
    }  


     public static char determineGrade(float average,float maxScore) {
         float percent = 100*(average/maxScore); 
         char grade = 'A';
       if( percent >= 90.0){
            grade = 'A';
       }else if( percent >= 80.0){
            grade = 'B';
       }else if( percent >= 60.0){
            grade = 'C';
       }else{
            grade = 'D';
       }
       return grade;

     }

}
```